# HTML link to redirect to third-party site after sending a request to my server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I would like to have a link or button on an HTML page that, when clicked, will redirect to an outside website page, *after* sending a GET or POST request to my web server. So rather than building a link URL that sends a request to my server which *then* in turn redirects to the outside website, I would like the redirect to happen at user-click time, where my server gets a simultaneous request specifying the click action, which I can then simply log on my server side.

On the server side, I don't need to actually respond to the GET/POST with anything useful, since I only want to log the request; i.e., I only want to make note of which user action was taken. I want the redirect to the outside URL to occur in the browser itself.

In essence, I am trying to do what [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=kittens) or [Fark](https://www.Fark.com) do when they present the user with a list of website links, where clicking a given link *first* redirects to their site, which *then* redirects to the actual outside website. But I would like to do that without having to wait on my web server to do the redirect, since it only needs to be *notified* of which link the user chose.

I think I could do this with an AngularJS `ng-click` attribute that does an `$http.get()` or `$http.post()`, and just ignore the returned (pending promise) result, and *then* change the `window.location` to point to the outside website's address. But the browser will then load the new outside URL before the response from the pending GET/POST request is received, leaving me to wonder if this would have any bad side effects on the browser, receiving a spurious response to the GET/POST during or after the outside page load.

Comment: Provide what you have tried so far, and how did that work?

Comment: You are correct in that  you can do this with an ajax `get` or `post`. Leaving before the ajax call has completed will not "harm anything", however you won't know if the request successfully logged on your server. If the browser redirects before the request get's to your server, it will cancel the request and you won't log. That being said, if you make your server side logging code fast you can wait for the response and **then** redirect in the browser and the user won't notice too much.

Comment: I am not sure what is the question. Please provide alteast one question mark in whole text. If you want to prevent "redirect" based on $http response then you should not ignore that promise result.

Comment: @bigless, In effect, I want clicking a link to send two requests, one as a GET or POST to my server, and the other as a redirect to an outside website. I want to avoid sending a request to my server and having the browser wait for a response to redirect to the website.

Comment: There are really only two options: 1) sending ajax and waiting for promise (if I understand, you dont process any data during that GET/POST - just pinging is usually under 300 ms. 2) using just href(GET) and then on server side redirect to third-party link optionally provided by query param.

Comment: Ad. 2 note that even on server side you can always "reject" GET by redirecting back to referer or "resolve" by redirecting to third-party link..ofc with refreshing the page and reloading whole angularjs..